# TinyMCE 4: How can i force Tiny editor to apply a single class for a p tag?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

In the recent version of TinyMCE editor( at this moment it's 4.0.5 ), When trying to apply a custom format for a text I've got this: `<p class="Fomat1">sample text</p>`
 and after applying the second format I've got this `<p class="Format1 Format2">sample text</p>`

But I normally have to get this `<p class="Format2">sample text</p>`

So what will I have to do to get the desired result ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this example which shows you how to override the built in formats and add a few custom ones to the styles menu :
http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/custom_formats.php